# Add icons to progress ring for windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am constructing a windows 8 app and I wanted to change my progress ring to be pictures or icons instead of the dots like regular rings are.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about coding this in c# or xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [default ProgressRing style with Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709924.aspx) and change in the way you want it. As you can see this style has 6 ellipses which represent the dots in Progress Ring. You will need to change each of them to whatever you want: Images or Rectangles or something else. Take a look on this article [Quickstart: styling controls (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465381.aspx)